# It's not working. Can anyone help me fix it?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

> I created this procedure but it said "PLS-00364: loop index variable 'DS' use is invalid" and "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist". How can I fix it?

```
 create or replace procedure thangmax3(
        nam IN number)
    as
    begin
        nam:=&nam;
        dbms_output.put_line('DS 3 thang nhieu khach den o ksan nhat nam '||nam);
        for ds in (select d.thang, d.sokhach from (select extract(month from thoigiannhan)as thang,COUNT(mathuephong)sokhach from HR.thong_tin_thue_phong 
                                    where extract(year from thoigiantra)=nam 
                                    group by  extract(month from thoigiannhan)
                                    order by COUNT(mathuephong) DESC) d 
                        where rownum<=3)
        loop
            dbms_output.put_line('Thang: '||ds.thang||'     '||'So khach: '||ds.soluong);
        end loop;
    end;
```

Comment: It's pretty clear that one of your tables does not exist. Check if you are accessing them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Then only "real" table involved in your code is

```
hr.thong_tin_thue_phong
```

As you preceded its name with owner name (`hr`), I guess that you currently aren't connected as `hr`. If that's so, `hr` should grant `select` privilege to you in order for this query to work.

So: connect as `hr` and run

```
grant select on thong_tin_thue_phong to user_that_runs_that_pl/sql_block;
```

---

As of another error you got: in `dbms_output.put_line` call within the loop, you're referencing `ds.soluong`, but - it doesn't exists in `FOR` loop's query: it has `thang` and `sokhach` so - use them.

---

Also, if you created a procedure with `IN` parameter, you don't *ask* for it using a substitution variable. Procedure would be:

```
create or replace procedure thangmax3(par_nam IN number)
  as
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('DS 3 thang nhieu khach den o ksan nhat nam '|| par_nam);
  for ds in (select d.thang, 
                    d.sokhach 
             from (select extract (month from thoigiannhan) as thang,
                          COUNT(mathuephong) sokhach 
                   from HR.thong_tin_thue_phong 
                   where extract (year from thoigiantra) = par_nam 
                   group by extract (month from thoigiannhan)
                   order by COUNT(mathuephong) DESC
                  ) d 
             where rownum<=3
            )
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line('Thang: '||ds.thang||'     '||'So khach: '||ds.sokhach);
  end loop;
end;
```

You'd call it as

```
begin
  thangmax3(&nam);
end;
/
```